# Why my JWplayer not working in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, jwplayer6, jwplayer7, getcomputedstyle

I am using a jwplayer in my website. but I am getting this error. Anyone can please tell me that why I get this error. 
Error loading player:
`window.getComputedStyle(...)` is null.

I find some solution but I cannot understand what to do. 
and I use google chrome, safari, microsoft edge and IE jwplayer run perfectly.
so any one please.

[image]

here,Is the image. that show you what's my problem.

Comment: can you add/post a snippet of the source javascript to your question?

Comment: Actually i can't post my code. for personal reason. but i am telling you that i am using jwplayer api and that api is not supported in mozilla firefox.

Comment: without a snippet of what's being passed to the function, it's rather difficult to debug specifics.  Most likely, the element being passed in the function can't be found; if it's a class or ID that's assigned via javascript and not static in the DOM, you may have a race condition/sequence of operations issue causing the failure.  Also, you may want to review the "notes" section here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle#Notes

Comment: Not find any help from this link. have you other option.?

Comment: JW Player is supported in Firefox.

Comment: you may also want to check if there are other javascript errors on the page that may be resulting in the likely race condition causing a dynamically attributed video element to not be detected.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Firefox? I see bug reports pointing to this error occurring with iframes set to display: none in older versions of FF.